# Simple jquery get function not working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to this, but I have tried for 2 hours on every page and example possible....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateCart(itemid,todo)  
   {
   $.get("updatecart.php?itemnumber=" + itemid + "&todo=" + todo);
   }
</script>
```

I have an html element to trigger the above code on click:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='UpdateCart("60813","remove");'>Remove Item</a>
```

For the life of me, i can't get it to work... When I try it with regular ajax coding, it works, but i'm trying minimize code. also, I have tested the updatecart.php manually with url variables and it works fine and does what it should.

Comment: code for html exlement:

<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='UpdateCart("60813","remove");'>Remove Item</a>

Comment: don't know why it wont let me post that code in the original question....

Comment: you should get the response and status to see what goes wrong

Comment: should your script include have the js at the end of jquery-1.10.1.min

Comment: @Orangepill OMG OMG THAT WAS IT!! man ... i hate programming sometimes. the little stupid stuff ALWAYS gets me!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're getting the contents of the page, but then not doing anything with the ajax response.  Did you mean to do something like this?

```
$.get("updatecart.php?itemnumber=" + itemid + "&todo=" + todo, function(resp){
   $('#target').html(resp);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) I don't see them passing the parameters like you are doing. Try some of their suggestions. Here is one.

```
$.get("updatecart.php", { itemnumber: itemid, todo: todo } );
```

Comment: In your updatecart.php how are you returning the data? Here's a small example that I wrote that works. Sorry, didn't mean to hit return. Give me a second and I'll post the code.